# scipy.integrate.solve_bvp for Neumann boundary conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numerical-methods

The question is what it says on the tin. I'm trying to numerically solve a boundary value problem and my friend is asking me whether the solver would work for these conditions. The page for the solver doesn't give the conditions we have i.e. `bc(y(a),y(b), p) = 0` but the form of our question is `y(0) = some constant value` and `y'(b) = 0`, giving our Neumann conditions, Would you need to rewrite the function to have a first order reduction like in the shooting method?

Comment: What exactly did you try? It looks as simple as `def bc(u0, ub): return [u0[0]-y0, ub[1]];`.

Comment: this is just a theoretical question about this specific black box solver. Also, what do you mean in your notation?

Comment: This is the function that encodes your boundary conditions, assuming that the state is `u(t) = [ y(t), y'(t) ]`, and `y0` contains the given constant value `someconstantvalue`. To be more specific one would need to know more about the BVP, ideally some code you tried but failed to get to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you are solving some second order ODE

```
y''(t) = F(t,y(t), y'(t))
```

For the first order system use the state vector `u = [y, v] = [y, y']`. Then the minimum to call the BVP solver is

```py
def ode(t,u): y,v = u; return [v, F(t,y,v)];
def bc(u0, ub): return [u0[0]-y0, ub[1]];

y0 = someconstantvalue;

t_init = [0,b];
u_init = [[y0, y0], [0, 0]];
res = solve_bvp(ode, bc, t_init, u_init)
```

Always check `res.success` or at least print out `res.message`. You might need a better initial guess, for non-linear problems different initial guesses can give different solutions. `res.sol` contains the solution as an interpolating function, for generating plots it is better to use this function than the sparse collection of internal steps in `res.x` and `res.y`